# C# StopWatch max duration on 32 bit PC

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I want to use the StopWatch class to improve time stamp accuracy in a 24/7 production environment. What is the max duration this class can count on a 32 bit machine? When it rolls does it just reset to zero? I noticed the StopWatch.Elapsed is a TimeSpan whose TotalMilliseconds is a double, but StopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds is a long.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs,ceb0ba9cc88de82e, `StopWatch` doesn't just count up in some thread, it calculates the difference between two time stamps, using a 64-bit integer, regardless of your machine's native word size. Whether this throws or overflows would depend on if you were in a checked or unchecked context.

Comment: Stopwatch is not accurate, not like DateTime or TickCount which are calibrated against an Internet time server.  It merely has a very high resolution, provided by an unspecified frequency source on the motherboard that runs at electronic component tolerances.  It is guaranteed to drift significantly from the true clock time, 1 minute per month for a crystal, temperature is the biggest source of drift.  Cheap machines tend to use the processor clock.  So just do the math, Math.Pow(2, 64) / 3E9 seconds is about 195 years.  You won't be around when it rolls over.

Comment: @Preston Guillot: Thanks for the 64-bit info, that's the piece I was missing.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thanks for the info; you steered me clear of trouble.